# Wrapper-class for Java array of generic instantiation of its elements

Tags: java, arrays, generics, types, garbage-collection

I'm currently writing a Game in Java.
In this game I am using arrays as data-structure for stuff like bullets.
Now I failed writing a wrapper-class around arrays using a generic type.
I constructed following example to demonstrate my problem.

```
    public class CoolArray< E extends MyInterface > {
        private final E[] array;
        public int aliveElements;

        public CoolArray( final Class< ? extends MyInterface > clazz, int size ) {
            array = (E[])Array.newInstance( clazz, size );
            for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
                // i would like to instantiate all array elements
                // to avoid constant object allocation at runtime
                try {
                    array[i] = clazz.newInstance(); // always throws NullPointerException
                } catch ( Exception e ) { } // omitted
            }
            aliveElements= 0;
        }

        public E get( int i ) {
            return array[ i ];
        }
        // rest omitted ...
    }
```

This should be my array-wrapper class. I create this array when a level is loaded. In the *update* and *render* methods of the game, I iterate only *aliveElements*-Elements of the array.

MyInterface contains method-stubs such as *update* and *render*...

Now, whenever I shoot a bullet, I call some *init* method on the Element at position *aliveElements*. I do this to avoid garbage collection.

```
    myCoolArray.get( myCoolArray.aliveElements ).init( ... )
```

And this is the part that fails because of a *ClassCastException* no matter how I try to instantiate every single element in the array.

Note: I am well aware that in above example I will get a *NullPointerException* because I didn't instantiate the elements! That is not the problem.

Google, some books and other questions here taught me, that generic types cannot be instantiated in Java. So now my question is: Is there a way around this?

I don't want to allocate new Objects in the *update* or *render* method, because I am scared of what the garbage collector will do to the frame-rate from time to time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, why I get the `InstantiationException` when I call `array[i] = clazz.newInstance()`.
It is because the Class I pass in has no default Constructor.
The class looks like:

```
    public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
        SomeField someField;
        public MyClass( SomeField someField ) {
            this.someField = someField;
        }
        // omitted
    }
```

To get it running i changed MyInterface to be an `abstract class` which I extend instead of inherit from. I put the `Constructor` with the `SomeField` Argument into that `Superclass` and made the default constructor private for safety reasons.

Then I changed the code where instantiate the generic class with code that calles the constructor with the `SomeField` argument.

Here is the complete code of all classes for the solution. Since I worked quite some time on this problem, I figured I share all of it here in the hope of saving someone else the trouble...

The new Superclass:

```
    public abstract class Superclass {
        protected SomeField someField;
        /**
        * DO NOT use this constructor! Just don't!
        */
        @SuppressWarnings( "unused" )
        private Superclass() {
        }

        public Superclass( SomeField someField ) {
            this.someField = someField;
        }

        public abstract void update( float delta );
        public abstract void render();
    }
```

The new generic Array implementation:

```
    public class QuickArray< E extends Superclass > {
        private final E[] array;
        private int elementCount;

        @SuppressWarnings( { "unchecked" } )
        public QuickArray( final Class< E > clazz, final SomeField someField, final int size ) {
            array = (E[])Array.newInstance( clazz, size );
            for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
                try {
                    array[ i ] = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor( SomeField.class ).newInstance( someField );
                } catch ( Exception e ) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            elementCount = 0;
        }

        public E get( final int i ) {
            return array[ i ];
        }
        // some other fancy methods
    }
```

A test class to put into the array:

```
    public class MyClass extends Superclass {
        public MyClass( SomeField someField ) {
            super( someField );
        }

        @Override
        public void update( float delta ) {
            // update
        }

        @Override
        public void render() {
            // render
        }

        // some other fancy methods
    }
```

And here is how the array is initialized:

```
    SomeField someField = new SomeField();
    QuickArray< MyClass > myArray = new QuickArray< MyClass >( MyClass.class, someField, CAPACITY );
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all: the class you write is pretty much just `ArrayList` with an additional restriction on the element types. Try if you can just use that (or wrap it). Even if you end up not doing that, implementing `Collection<E>` or *at least* `Iterable<E>` should help writing reusable code.

Next: you say you solved the `NullPointerException` but don't tell us how you instantiated your objects.

And yes, there is a way around not being able to do `new E()`, which involves having a `Class<E` around, which luckily you already have: you can simply use [`c.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) to fill your internal array (if your `MyInterface` implementations all have public no-arguments constructors).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Well, you are not correct with the ArrayList part. I didn't want to use ArrayLists because of the performance issue when inserting and removing elements. Especially when called multiple times each frame from *update()* and *render()*.
Well, I didn't mean I solved the `NullPointerException` I just wanted to know what I have to write there to make it work.
You are absolutely right, it is `array[i].newInstance()`.
But when I wrote that, I got an `InstantiationError`. That is the one I wanted to get fixed.

Comment: You can just use a pre-filled `ArrayList` (just as you're using a pre-filled array). And I never said anything about `array[i].newInstance()`. What is the message of the `InstantiationError`? An `InstantiationError` should never occur here, possibly an `InstantiationException`. Is that what happened? Last but not least: post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), because it looks like there's a lot of information that we don't have (but we need it to help you).

Comment: I am really grateful for your enthusiasm towards solving my problem! But I just posted the solution to my problem myself.
You are right again, i meant `InstantiationException` and it looked like `java.lang.InstantiationException: generics.MyClass`. It pointed to the line where I call `array[ i ] = clazz.newInstance();`
That's why I figured that there must be something wrong in that line but it was the constructor of my class that led to that error. My detailed explanation below should leave no questions.

Comment: @androverso: so it actually was the problem I hinted at with "if your MyInterface implementations all have public no-arguments constructors" ;-) Glad you could fix it. Out of curiosity: didn't the exception have a message that told you what the problem was?

Comment: The exception: (copy & paste)
`java.lang.InstantiationException: generics.MyClass`
`at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)`
`at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)`
`at generics.CoolArray.<init>(CoolArray.java:14)`
`at generics.CoolArrayTest.create(CoolArrayTest.java:12)`
`at generics.CoolArrayTest.main(CoolArrayTest.java:6)`

I couldn't get anything from that :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you can't do `new E()` in the loop in your constructor (because the compiler can't guarantee that there is a no-arg constructor for all possible values of `E`), but since you know ahead of time how to construct all of your concrete subclasses, I suggest incorporating some code along the lines of this (assuming `Bullet` and `Wall` subclasses of `MyInterface`):

```
private static <C extends MyInterface> C create (Class<C> c) {
    MyInterface created;

    if (c == Bullet.class) {
        created = new Bullet ();
    } else if (c == Wall.class) {
        created = new Wall ();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Unknown class " + c);
    }

    return c.cast (created);
}
```

You may prefer to use polymorphism to decide which subclass to instantiate. Then you create

```
interface Factory<E extends MyInterface> {
    E create();
}

class BulletFactory implements Factory<Bullet> {
    public Bullet create() {
        return new Bullet();
    }
}
```

etc., etc., and you pass in the correct `Factory` object to the constructor.

Finally, I notice that the `Class` object that you are passing in is not correctly constrained to make the generic parameter of the class, the constructor should be defined as

```
public CoolArray(final Class<E> clazz, int size) {
    array = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         array[i] = GenericFactory.create(clazz);
    }
    aliveElements= 0;
}
```

or

```
public CoolArray(final Class<E> clazz, final Factory<E> factory, int size) {
    array = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
         array[i] = factory.create();        }
    aliveElements= 0;
}
```

if you decide to use the factory approach.

(You also don't need the cast to `E` in your `get` method.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This looks really complicated for something that should be quite simple. I haven't tried it because I figured out what I did wrong the whole time. I appreciate your effort though!